# Referencing struct member in documentation using doxygen not working; struct member not appearing in documentation

Tags: c++, struct, hyperlink, doxygen

Running doxygen for

```
namespace BV
{
namespace Data
{
typedef struct Station {
    uint offsetId;              //! The ID of a station is generated by adding an offset to a base (example: 1000)
    uint id;                    //! The ID of the station (see {@link Station.offsetId} for more details)
    QString name;               //! Name of the station
    QStringList lineSwitches;   //! A list of available lines the passanger can switch to from the station
} Station;


...
}
}
```

returns warning

> /home/USER/Projects/HelloWorld/src/csvparser.h:16: warning: unable to resolve link to `Station.offsetId' for \link command

Initially I only had `offsetId` instead of `Station.offsetId` but after looking online I saw a bunch of examples (including here on SO) that were describing this to be the way. Besides I also want to reference this member in other parts of my header.

Not only do I get the warning from above but I just took a look at the generated HTML documentation for my structure and for my surprise it wasn't even there:

> **Public Attributes**
>
> uint  **id**
>
> ```
> The ID of a station is generated by adding an offset to a base (example: 1000)
> ```
>
> QString   **name**
>
> ```
> The ID of the station (see **Station.offsetId** for more details)
> ```
>
> QStringList   **lineSwitches**
>
> ```
> Name of the station.
> ```

The **Station.offsetId** is just a broken link.

Comment: Please have a look at "Putting documentation after members" in the documentation and change //! into //!< and report back. Why are you using the construct {@link Station.offsetId}  (you tried to explain somethings, maybe revise it a bit after the previous remark) and not just Station.offsetId or \ref Station.offsetId or #offsetId or \ref offsetId?

Comment: Ah, shoot. I completely forgot about the `<`. As for the `{@link ... }` - I'm used to it from when I started using doxygen. Then I had a long gap and now I've started again. I will look into both of your suggestions.

Comment: It works like a charm. Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can approve it. Also the `{@command ...}` while uncommon for doxygen documentation works even for `@link`. I guess it's the curly braces that create some sort of a scope. Otherwise the `@endlink` is expected. But I will try to use `@ref` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation as stated in the question uses `//!` as comment strings, this is intended for usage before the member. When having the documentation after the member one should use `//!<`. See also  "Putting documentation after members" in the doxygen manual.

As a second part it is not necessary to use: `{@link Station.offsetId}` (actually `\link` should also have a `\endlink`. Better is to use `\ref` or `#` e.g. `\ref Station.offsetId` or `#offsetId` or `\ref offsetId` or in (this case) just `Station.offsetId`.